# Create new folder for the project to get build into throught script C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, directory, version

With the help of the internet i found a way to Update the Version of my build each time i build it.

But i still have to create a new folder for it by hand if i dont want to override the last build. Is there a way to create a folder named after the build version that unity uses to build the game into? Like

Game V1.5 -\> Build into C/Folder/Folder/SaveDestination/V1.5

Game V1.6 -\> Build into C/Folder/Folder/SaveDestination/V1.6

Game V1.6.1 -\> Build into C/Folder/Folder/SaveDestination/V1.6.1

...

I hope you understand what I mean and I apologise in advance for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unity's [`BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html) API to change the directory to which you want to build. You can combine this with your own [`BuildPlayerOptions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPlayerOptions.html) to change the path to your build.

Below is an example on how you could achieve this using Unity's `MenuItem`. This script gets a copy of the current player options and changes it's `locationPathName` to add your version to it. Do note that you need to set your builder's path to the parent directory of where you want your versioned directories to be (if your desired directory is `C/Folder/Folder/SaveDestination/V1.6.1`, the builder's path should be `C/Folder/Folder/SaveDestination`).

I don't have Unity open right now, but this code should give you the gist of how to get things to work.

```cs
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;

public class BuildPlayerWithVersion : MonoBehaviour
{
    [MenuItem("Build/Build With Version")]
    public static void MyBuild()
    {
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions(); 
        BuildPlayerWindow.DefaultBuildMethods.GetBuildPlayerOptions(buildPlayerOptions);

        // Get your build version here
        string version = "V1.6.2"
        string path = Path.Join(buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName, version);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);      
        buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = path;
        
        BuildReport report = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
        BuildSummary summary = report.summary;

        if (summary.result == BuildResult.Succeeded)
        {
            Debug.Log("Build succeeded: " + summary.totalSize + " bytes");
        }

        if (summary.result == BuildResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Build failed");
        }
    }
}
```